# GWT HTML 5 Input Type Phone

Tags: html, gwt

I have a GWT application which im targeting to run on mobile devices.  I'd like to use the new HTML5 `input type="tel"` to accept phone input and get mobile devices to prompt for correct keyboard entry (numeric).

I'm trying to use a GWT TextBox, but cannot see a way to have it render HTML with correct input type.

Any ideas on this one?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

Simple way

```
TextBox tel=new TextBox();
tel.getElement().setAttribute("type", "tel");

TextBox email=new TextBox();
email.getElement().setAttribute("type", "email");

TextBox url=new TextBox();
url.getElement().setAttribute("type", "url");
```

Comment: This will trip up if running on IE <= v9. Consider hand-coding a for these versions of IE and using GWT's deferred binding to manage that extra code.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of different inputs (also a phone input) in mgwt ( http://www.m-gwt.com ) which is GWT for mobile devices. You may want to take a look at it.

Comment: Took a look at this library today.  Nice set of widgets thanks for the recommendation